# pond pump humming, but water keeps flowing

Tags: pump, electric-motor, pond

I have a pond pump `TidalWave PAF-25SV` which started humming very loud, although it keeps on pumping water as before.

[image]

So I took it out of the basket, removed the intake screen, cleaned up any debris (not much though). From there I can observe the impeller, and it does not seem to be clogged with anything. I can't really access the impeller, as it is covered with chamber, but I can rotate it with a screwdriver. It does rotate, however not very easily (not sure how *easy* it has to rotate?), so I'm wondering if this is a impeller bearing issue? If so, does it mean it can't be replaced, and the whole pump needs to be replaced?

Thanks.

Comment: Small appliance repair is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pump motors usually spin fairly easily. My guess is the bearing seals have failed and the extra drag is causing the motor to buzz or hum.

It is possible you can disable and get to the bearings on the shaft. It is normally the output shaft bearing that fails.

A high quality double sealed bearing for a small pump like that will normally be only a few dollars, and you do want a type ZZ or 2RS with most brand  zz= double sealed 2RS is 2 rubber seal , so look for a number like 188zz or 608-2RS  these are examples of the 2 smallest motor bearings I have on the shelf that I use in motor applications both are well under 1$ each and I usually purchase 10 at a time because they are cheaper but you want the rubber sealed.

Be careful on disassembly as there may be a seal just like an oil seal on a car crank shaft that is usually able to be re used if careful.

But it’s well worth it to repair a nice motor for 2$  and an hours time that may save over 100$.

Comment: thanks a lot for detailed answer! Can you guess (I know it's hard but based on your experience, you might be able to), how to access the bearing on this particular model? That black bottom chamber (where the motor fits in) does not seem to move at all, so I'm not sure how I can get inside. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I would guess the 4 Phillips screws on the top outside are long and hold the bottom in place.